# How do I box an equation array?

Tags: equations, box

I want to have an equation array (the environment `eqnarray`) contained in a box. The only way I know is to use the `\boxed` command. This works for

```
\begin{eqnarray}
\boxed{1+1}&=&2
\end{eqnarray}
```

but fails for

```
\begin{eqnarray}
\boxed{1+1&=&2}
\end{eqnarray}
```

How should I box the whole thing?

Comment: (1) never use `eqnarray` it is broken in many ways (2) see the `mathtools` and `empheq` packages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`eqnarray` is an environment from the LaTeX kernel which does its job, but [there is better on the market](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/82917). You use the `\boxed` command, which means that you are already loading `amsmath`, so you should use its display alignment environments. This being said, it's true that `\boxed` doesn't work across cells. The package `mathtools` (an extension to `amsmath`) provides a macro `\Aboxed` which does.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools} % loads amsmath

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\Aboxed{ a&=b } \\
c&= d
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put multiple aligned equations in a box I'd recommend the `empheq` package. For example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,empheq}
\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align*}
a &= b \\
c &= d
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]